# New enviolo hub shift is locked

Tags: hub, continuously-variable-transmission

My shift mechanism is locked on a new hub. Will not shift at all. Still in max overdrive.  Don't want to force it.

Comment: Is this a brand-new hub?  Has it ever worked?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to provide more context. Did you get your hub replaced and it now doesn't work after assembly? Are you running their cable-accentuated/manual drivetrain or the AutomatiQ? Did you swap it, did your bike shop do this, are you still under warranty? Anyhow, they have great help resource under https://support.enviolo.com/hc/en-us